# Filtering data using Angular and checkboxes

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure how can you filter given products based on the material with a checkbox ? Should i be using pipes ? Should i be using only filter ?

**Product-list.HTML**

```
<div class="category-container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Cotton</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label for="defaultCheck1" class="form-check-label">
        Cotton
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div *ngFor="let product of products"  class="col-6">
      <app-product-card [product]="product" ></app-product-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Product-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/_services/product.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/_models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: Product;
  products: Product[];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProducts();
  }

  loadProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
      this.products = products;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Filter to filter on the basis of the checkbox event.

```
loadProducts() {
   this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
      this.products = products;
      let a = this.products.filter(e => e.filtercondition == checkboxInput);
      this.products = a;
   }, error => {
      console.log(error);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only problem i face is that it always seems to be filtered. Maybe im doing the checkboxInput event wrong ?  const a = this.products.filter(e => e.material === this.cotton); this.products = a;